# (novice) wrote 2 functions but getting error after error after error

Tags: php

I've been trying to get further in PHP and writing functions daily to practice but started to get the feeling I'm either overcomplicating or doing it completely wrong.

My 2 functions for this script:

```
function getFilesAndContent($path)
{
    $data = [];

    $folderContents = new DirectoryIterator($path);

    foreach ($folderContents as $fileInfo) {
        if ($fileInfo->isDot()) {
            break;
        }

        $fileData = [
            'file_name' => $fileInfo->getName(),
        ];

        if ($fileInfo->getExtension()) {
            $fileData['contents'] = getFileContents($fileInfo->getPathname());
        }

        $data = $fileData;
    }

    return $data;
}

function getFileContents($path)
{
    $names = file_get_contents($fileInfo->getPathname());

    $names = implode("\n", $names);

    sort($names);

    $contents = '';

    foreach ($names as $name) {
        $contents += $name . ' (' . strlen($name) . ')<br>';
    }

    return $name;
}
```

All I want to do is:

```
foreach (getFilesAndContent('.') as $data) {
    echo $data['file_name'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $data['contents'];

    echo '<hr>';
```

The error: 
`FATAL ERROR Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DirectoryIterator::getName() in /home4/phptest/public_html/code.php70(5) : eval()'d code:15 Stack trace: #0 /home4/phptest/public_html/code.php70(5) : eval()'d code(45): getFilesAndContent('.') #1 /home4/phptest/public_html/code.php70(5): eval() #2 {main} thrown on line number 15`

The file it's supposed to read is a simple .txt files with a list of names, nothing more.

Any help appreciated! Also wondering if it's better to just rewrite the entire functions if I keep getting so many errors?

Comment: In `'file_name' => $fileInfo->getName(),`, there is [no such method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) as `getName`. You likely meant `getBasename()`. (Also, in `getFileContents` there's all kinds of things being wrong; but you can just call `file_get_contents` directly instead of `getFileContents` and it should work.) (You also almost certainly wanted to `continue`, not `break`, and if the file is _not_ a dotfile, not when file _is_ a dotfile.) (You also wanted to see if file's extension is "txt", not if it has any extension.)

Comment: "Also wondering if it's better to just rewrite the entire functions if I keep getting so many errors?" If you think it's unsalvageable, sure. But it's usually after a lot of effort to salvage it, not a first response. Typically, you'd see what error you're getting, then correct it (trying not to change anything else, so you don't make more errors by fixing one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many things to fix in your code, for example changing undefined method `getName()` to something else, don't use `break` to skip because it will exit the loop, using `explode(string $separator, string $string)` to split string by separator, return `$contents` from `getFileContents()` function to return final concatenated string, etc.

I think, your goal is to display all *.txt files and its contents, with length for each line in contents. Try this:

```
$d = dir('.');
while (($file = $d->read()) !== false) { // iterate all files
    if (preg_match('/\.txt$/', $file)) { // filter only file ends with .txt
        $contents = explode("\n", file_get_contents($d->path . '/' . $file)); // get file contents, split by \n
        array_walk($contents, function(&$item) {
            $item .= ' (' . strlen($item) . ')';
        }); // add (length) in the end of each line

        // display it
        echo '<strong>' . $file . '</strong><br>';
        echo implode('<br>', $contents);
        echo '<hr>';
    }
}
```